# Is there any public Instagram API for Story? Get Instagram Stories Json

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

The title says it all. I was wondering if there is any **workaround or public API endpoint** which allows you to get **story data back** from public users? I have tried using this endpoint, https://www.instagram.com/stories/**username**/**storyID**/?__a=1, **unfortunately**, this only returns the user's profile ID, profile picture, and username. **It does not return anything about the story video which is what I am looking for**.

Below is an example link of the stories from the UFC, (remember this example link may stop working as stories only last for 24h)

https://www.instagram.com/stories/ufc/2427177098954142525/?__a=1

Any help is much appreciated.